# Trying to pull the required rows from the single table with applying conditional statements on columns in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried in n-number ways to solve this solution but unfortunately I got stuck in all the ways..

source table

```
id   year jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
1234 2014 05  06  12  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
1234 2013 05  06  12  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
```

Task: Assume that we are currently at March 2014, and we need 12 months back date ...(i.e., from Mar 2013 to Feb 2014, and the remaining values needs to be zero except year and id.)

Solution:

```
id   year jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
1234 2014 05  06  0   0   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1234 2013 0   0   12   15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
```

This needs a code solution for SQL Server 2008. I would be very happy if any body can solve this.

Note:

I got stuck to pull the column names dynamically.

Comment: A select statement can return a fixed number of columns only. Do you want the value of certain columns be replaced with 0 based on your conditions? Will it not be easier to do that in your application code?

Comment: You can always use 'case when' column is not 12 month ago then 0...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select id, year, case when DATEDiff(month, getdate(), convert(datetime, year + '-01-01'))) < 12 then jan else 0, 
DATEDiff(month, getdate(), convert(datetime, year + '-02-01'))) < 12 then fab else 0 ....
```